# MySQL Not Inserting Into Column

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, forms

I have the code below:

```
    <html><body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","will","blahblah");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("blahblah", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO links (link, notes, username)
VALUES
('$_POST[link]','$_POST[notes]','$_POST[username]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 link added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
</body></html>
```

It should insert a link and notes and a username into my database but it doesn't. I am clueless as to why and would appreciate some help with it! It is getting these values from the form below:

```
   <div id="stylized" class="myform">
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="user.php">
<label>Username
<span class="small">Enter Your Username</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="username" />

<label>Link
<span class="small">Paste Your Link</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="link" />

<label>Notes
<span class="small">Add Some Notes</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="password" id="notes" />

<button type="submit"></button>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</form>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting? (btw, the username input is "name" instead of "username")

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: There is no error it just doesn't insert it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least three problems, with your code :

**First**, when injecting strings into an SQL query, you must escape it, using [**`mysql_real_escape_string()`**](http://fr.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) :

```
$link = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link']);
$notes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['notes']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

$sql="INSERT INTO links (link, notes, username)
VALUES ('$link','$notes','$username')";
```

**Third**, in your PHP code, **you must use the `name` attribute of your input fields** -- and not their **`id`** attributes.

Considering your HTML code looks like this :

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="username" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="link" />
<input type="text" name="password" id="notes" />
```

You should work with :

- `$_POST['name']`, and not `$_POST['username']`
- `$_POST['email']`, and not `$_POST['link']`
- `$_POST['password']`, and not `$_POST['notes']`

**Note :** using a `name` and an `id` that are that different leads to troubles ;-)

---

So, to summarize, your code should look a bit more like this :

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

$sql="INSERT INTO links (link, notes, username)
VALUES ('$email','$password','$name')";
```

**Note :** you should use the same names for the input fields, and the fields in the table -- it would make your code easier to understand.

Comment: first is not a problem. fair use

Answer (score 1):

Replace it :

```
$sql="INSERT INTO links (link, notes, username)
VALUES
('$_POST[link]','$_POST[notes]','$_POST[username]')";
```

with:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO links (link, notes, username)
VALUES
('". mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']) ."','".
     mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']) ."','". 
     mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']) ."')";
```

Note that POST variables you're trying to use in Your query are completely different from those on your form

Answer (score 0):

The indexes of POST variables must match the names of the form items.

So either write:

`<input type="text" name="link" id="link" />` or use `$_POST[email]`

Adapt for the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

`id` attributes are meaningless when submitting the form. You probably want to swap the `name` and `id` attributes.

Currently, `$_POST['name']`, `$_POST['email']` and `$_POST['password']` are being submitted instead of `$_POST['username']`, `$_POST['link']` and `$_POST['notes']`.

Your code is also vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/601300/427545).

Answer (score 0):

The items in $_POST are indexed by name attribute, not by id.